# What is the most accurate estimate for the total number of Palestinian deaths due to ongoing conflict?

Tags: 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza

When reporting on Palestinian deaths, many organisations are quoting a figure of roughly 30,000 with around 20,000 being women and children. See for example [here](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/longform/2023/10/9/israel-hamas-war-in-maps-and-charts-live-tracker) or [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/02/29/middleeast/gaza-death-toll-30000-israel-war-hnk-intl/index.html). However, as I understand it, this is the number of deaths resulting from direct Israeli military action. That is, those who have been killed as a result of bombing, gunfire, and the like.

Due to Israel's [blockade on food and water](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/israel-palestine-war-fighting-human-animals-defence-minister), and cutting off of electricity, malnutrition, famine and starvation are now all widespread in Gaza. The UN aid coordination office OCHA estimates that one in four Gazans are facing ["catastrophic levels of food insecurity"](https://news.un.org/en/story/2024/03/1147112). Moreover, Israeli military action has destroyed or rendered inoperable almost all hospitals in Gaza. For example, as of January, CNN reports that 22 out of 24 hospitals in north Gaza are [either destroyed or inoperable](https://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2024/01/middleeast/gaza-hospitals-destruction-investigation-intl-cmd/) (see also [here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/feb/19/gaza-nasser-hospital-out-of-service-who-israel-palestine-raid-hamas)). As a result, many Gazans with serious medical conditions such as cancer are [facing death](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-65393231) due to lack of care.

What is the most accurate estimate of the *total* number of deaths amongst Gazans due to the ongoing Israel-Hamas conflict? That is deaths taking into account starvation, lack of access to medical treatment, and diseases linked to lack of clean water.

Comment: Why are you thinking this number includes only direct deaths? I don't see that stated anywhere

Comment: @CommandMaster, this has been my understanding based on what I've read. I can't find a reference at the moment. If you have info to the contrary, then please post that as an answer.

Comment: No offense, but are you new to wars? There's not going to be a 'most accurate' number settled for quite some time. Compare with conflicting reports about Russia-Ukraine, or even Ethiopia. Anyhow, related Q https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83052/are-there-more-reliable-sources-for-the-death-toll-in-the-israel-hamas-war-than

Comment: Deleted my +13/-3 moderator-edited answer, which was reduced to only its first, no-worries, part, casting doubt that there were missing casualties and that the numbers of starving were *currently* consequently quite low. The second, less positive, half of that answer, was flagged in [meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6803/21531) and was subsequently edited out, which is why I deleted the answer. As a result, upvoted this question.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualties_of_the_Tigray_War for instance.

Comment: There was also a lot of [malnutrition](https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/feature/2022/06/20/hidden-hunger-micronutrient-deficiencies-in-the-west-bank-and-gaza) and [problems with medical care](https://www.btselem.org/gaza_strip/20230404_in_2022_too_israel_prevented_thousands_of_palestinians_in_need_of_medical_care_from_leaving_gaza_for_treatment) even before the war started, so you'd have to prove that deaths were due to additional measures rather than the continuation of previous Israeli policies (which varied in severity over time).

Comment: Asking for a single number is bad when dealing with uncertainties. A single number can never adequately describe the center and level of uncertainty. We simply don't know how many Palestinians died so far. Better ask for accurate ranges or minimal numbers. Something like: what is a reasonable (say 95% sure) lower limit on the number of dead Palestinians?

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2024/mar/21/we-are-about-to-witness-the-most-intense-famine-since-world-war-ii-in-gaza), epidemiologists in London and Baltimore estimate that through to August, the total death toll from all causes to be between 48,210 and 193,180. Under certain scenarios (what they call the 'with escalation' scenario) these figures could be even higher.